# API design - Is it a good practice to dictate method order?

Tags: java, api

```
public abstract class A { 
    private int result=-1;
    public void final doExecuteMySpecialAlgorithm() {
         result=0;
         //do something here and get a new result
         //it won't be -1.
    }
    public int getResult() { 
        if(result==-1) 
             throw new RuntimeException("Invoke my special algorithm first!");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Isn't getResult method a bad design - It is forcing user to invoke another method before it is invoked? How would you workaround this? Would your rather return -1 or say null (in case of an object type) and let the caller figure out what to do will a null return? or if you are sure that it won't be null, but for the return to be not null, you would have to invoke  another method before invoking getResult method, would you just throw a RuntimeException? (or a checked exception?)

Comment: Can't you make `doExecuteMySpecialAlgorithm` actually return the value?

Comment: yes, that's possible as well. But, what if I have say different results from that single method, which could be obtained by simply calling getResultPrimary(), getResultSecondary().

Comment: I would have a separate class, with its own getters, for encapsulating the result.  Have `doExecuteMySpecialAlgorithm` return an instance of that class.

Comment: An alternative would be to have `getResult` actually call `doExecuteMySpecialAlgorithm` itself if `result == -1`, instead of throwing the exception; and do likewise in `getResultSecondary()` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways here. Either make it synchronous (i.e. `doExecuteMySpecialAlgorithm` actually returns the result) or asynchronous.

The first is obvious, the second can be accomplished by returning a `Future` object for example. Either way, the caller doesn't need to think which is the proper order to call methods.

In some cases it may be alright to enforce the calling order of methods (such as the `doFinal` method in crypto classes), but you should still avoid making the code in a way that the user has to think carefully about how he's going to call your methods. Obviously he needs to know what to call, but if he needs to call 5 methods in a specific order, it probably means there should be only 1 method.

I mean after all, if you want to force the caller to call `method1()`, `method2()`, `method3()` in order, you should really make him call `method()`, which inside calls private methods `method1()`, `method2()` and `method3()`. That way you have the code well structured, but the caller can't fudge things up by calling the methods in the wrong order.

Comment: I think, I didn't word my question correctly. No this is not a problem of sync or async. It is more of a API design question - How would structure your code/API?

Comment: Yes, I think your update is more relevant to my question. The downside of having a single method is, that this single method would have to effectively return the output. But let's just say that there are multiple outputs. So for instance, my algorithm is probably creating two lists. Your suggestion would require me to create a class that will hide these two lists and my method would have to return an instance of this class. Well, now if you think about it, this return class is anemic in nature. It is serving as an empty container. Not quite useful? Reminds me of the anemic VO/DTO pattern.

Comment: Well, sadly Java lacks a "Pair" or "Tuple" class, which makes returning 2 values always a bit odd. Still, if the _end_ result is 2 values, that's what you should return (in a `Collection` for example, that way it's not locked into just 2 values). If the logic works so, that the first value is calculated in `method1()` and the second one in `method3()` (hypothetical parts of your algorithm), then there might be a different way about it, but not necessarily any better.

Comment: Ok, lets say, they are not return types of same data type? One is a String another is a List.

Comment: Then that's already a complex enough data type to warrant its own class. I mean classes are cheap and they just make the code more easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

In your example I'd do the following:

```
public abstract class A { 
    private int result=-1;
    public void final doExecuteMySpecialAlgorithm() {
         result=0;
         //do something here and get a new result
         //it won't be -1.
    }
    public int getResult() { 
        if(result==-1) 
             doExecuteMySpecialAlgorithm();
        return result;
    }
}
```

This way a user can do the 'special' algorithm first, or if they 'forget' to, you (as the API writer) catch it for them and do this (instead of throwing an error).

Doing this makes your object do the work for you (object oriented design), of course this is YOUR API design, and I would assume that there would be extensive documentation dictating that if I call `getResult` that I must first call `doExecuteMySpecialAlgorithm` ... whatever you choose to implement YOU must document that the user is ordered to call function X before function Y or undefined behavior might result (or throw an error).

Comment: what if doExecuteMySpecialAlgorithm throws an exception which I expect the caller to handle? it wouldn't really look nice if all your getResult methods also throw this exception up?

Comment: If you go this way, I would make the `doExecuteMySpecialAlgorithm()` private and rename `getResult()` into something more descriptive. Make the caller unable to call the algorithm at all, and rely on the result giving method.

Comment: @Jay; I aggree with @Kayaman, hide as much of the implementation as possible, and no it wouldn't look nice to `catch` everywhere you call that function, but it's also not particularly 'nice' to have to 'catch' as much as I do with the normal Java API's (put a `throws` at the end of a function in some base class and strict compilation rules and watch the fun ensue of the number of `try`'s you'll implement..) .. it goes with the territory of writing an API. Just think; how would YOU use this API? If YOU wouldn't like using the way you'd implement, then implement another way :)